# What does the "Failed to launch JVM" error mean when executing an .exe made with jpackage?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jpackage

I have a program which I have compiled into a runnable jar using the Eclipse IDE, and turned into a .exe file using jpackage.

However, the resulting file will not run successfully. It seemingly executes the first line of the code (which creates a .txt file for logging), and then throws the error "Failed to launch JVM".

I've tried looking into the manifest file for the program and making sure that the -main-class variable is correct in my jpackage command, but I can't see where the problem lies.

Here is my jpackage command:

```
jpackage -i "C:\Users\User\Documents\myprogram\jar" -n "myprogram" --main-class uk.co.myname.myprogram.MyProgram --main-jar "myprogram.jar" -d "C:\Users\User\Documents\myprogram\exe" --icon "C:\Users\User\Documents\myprogram\app icons\My Icon.ico"
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Are there any logs in the ".txt file for logging"? If not, try running `jpackage` with `--win-console` and then running the resulting executable from the command line; what output do you see, if any?

Comment: I have solved but thank you very much for answering! My problem was a combination of not reading the manifest file correctly, and also not writing file paths correctly (double \) in my config file :)